# Custom Fields in DevDemon Subscriptions

Tags: custom-fields, devdemon, subscriptions

Has anyone been able to get Custom Fields to work with the DevDemon Subscriptions add-on?

At the very bottom of this page (http://www.devdemon.com/documentation/tag/subs-subscribe/) there are two Note's relating to this:

- Note 1: Custom Member Fields are supported. Use the following format for form names m_field_id_XX. Example:
- Note 2: The setting "Is field visible in registration page?" on each Custom Member Field has to be set to "Yes".

I've tried this and can't get it to work.  Anyone had luck with this?

Comment: We have tested this on a couple of sites already. Do you have any template code you can share? (Make sure Note #2 is done, took us a while to catch that one)

Comment: Just noticed you need Subs 1.5.3, added the correct answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need Subscriptions 1.5.3 for custom member fields to be detected.

See: http://www.devdemon.com/expressionengine-addons/subscriptions

Comment: Thanks Manuel, I think the documentation update beat the new release to market.